# SSDT Schema compare to compare only specific objects

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, ssdt-bi

Is it possible to use schema compare in SSDT to compare only specific objects? Not object types, specific objects like 3 tables and 2 stored procedures instead of all tables and all stored procedures?

Comment: It is not possible using generic SSDT schema compare.
But you can use SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) to write a powershell script doing it.

Comment: Thanks, @Piotr, I will research SMO. If you have any resources, it'd be great. Thanks again.

Comment: Please check this one: https://powershell.org/2013/04/comparing-sql-server-table-schemas-with-powershell/

Comment: Here Microsoft documented steps to compare schema using SSDT. Hope it'll help you out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks @RajeshRanjan. I know how to do schema compares using SSDT, my question was if it's possible to filter objects for the comparison to avoid running the comparison on all the database and instead run it only on a few selected objects. I know you can filter by object types but I want to filter by specific object. Thanks anyway.